# Modifying custom Wordpress pages

Tags: wordpress

Sorry if this question is too basic (It would be great if someone could recommend me on a good resource/tutorial for starting up with wordpress development)

I am new to wordpress development. And I work on a Mac.
I downloaded MAMP, installed wordpress, and installed a custom theme which I bought online.
So far, I've been using the wordpress wp-admin interface to customize the theme.
I created a new Page called "myPage". I'm interested in making some design changes to myPage but the wp-admin tool is limited and I realized I have to start looking/modifying the code.

I'm using Netbeans, and created a new project of my local wordpress folder which contains the wp-admin, wp-content, wp-include folders.

However, I am not sure where in the code to find the page I created "myPage", in order to modify it.
I ran a search on all the code but I don't find any mention of it.

I guess my custom page is saved elsewhere? in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: About a good place for starting up with WordPress development, [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) here on the StackExchange network is another great resource to find information. It's just like StackOverflow, except it's *entirely* about WordPress development.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you can find your page in DB, check out [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-are-pages-in-the-database-wp-post-table) for more info.

To access your database, you need to go to url `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin`/  if everything is set right; or your local IP/phpMyAdmin/ if host alias is not set.

**EDITED**

If you are looking for file, you should look in `wpfolder/wp-content/themes/some-theme/` and now ether `page.php` or `content-page.php` I am not sure.

Comment: I know how to access the DB from phpMyAdmin. I actually use SQL Pro for that.  I looked in my DB under wp_posts table and found the entry for my page.  However, this DB entry only consists of certain fields (some can be modified also from the wp-admin tool. However, I do not see how this entry can help me in modifying the design of my page.  For example: The default page (which was built by the theme designer) contains only a slider for photos.  I would like to add a few buttons. The theme's interface does not provide this option. That's the reason I'm looking into the code.  Thanks!

Comment: You haven't formulated your question right then, because your custom page is saved in DB...I will edit answer

Answer (score 0):

Drill down through wp-content > themes > to your theme's folder. Inside there you will find a file called page.php. That is your default page template. To double check this is the page being used, in your wordpress backend, edit the page and on the right hand side in the 'page attributes' panel, you will see a dropdown under 'Template'. You're purchased theme may have many templates, so that is how you can tell which one is being used.

Note: Creating a page inside of the wordpress backend does not actually create a new page file for that page.

Hope this helps.